# Exchange 2007 URL issue after Exchange 2013 migration

Tags: iis, exchange-2007, exchange-2013

We have a number of webpages that pull data from Exchange 2007. We recently migrated these mailboxes to 2013.

It appears the code uses a URL http://xxxxx2007/exchange/mailbox which points to \.\backendstorage\ which doesn't exist in 2013 anymore and has nothing similar.

To add to the confusion according to Microsoft this \.\backendstorage\ URL in IIS was phased out after 2003 so not sure why we have one in 2007.

I simply cannot figure out what URL is the replacement for this in 2013, I immediately thought of EWS but this fails.

Anyone had issues like this with Exchange migrations and third party code before?

Comment: Do you mean that you're pulling data to display on a webpage from public folders, or mailboxes?

Comment: Actually pulling full Emails out of the mailbox to place in this web front end to be processed

Comment: AFAIK this is no-longer possible with normal user mailboxes. You need to use Outlook to connect to the mailbox, and process the data through that. However, the last time I looked into this was when 2013 was RTM and I was trying to process different Excel files for user management. This may be different now.  @CharlesH

Comment: Interesting I guessed the code would have to change. I would imagine you can manipulate OWA to gain the same result. Thanks I'll have a look in to switching to using OWA instead of this backendstorage and feed back with what I find!